# Sort a linked list where odd positions are already sorted

Tags: sorting, linked-list

I need to sort a linked list where the elements in odd positions are already sorted. The idea now I have implemented is pretty naive and is as follows:

1. construct two new lists one with odd positions and other with even positions
2. Sort the the even position list
3. Merge the two sorted lists

Is there any optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. I don't believe there is a better method than that.

Comment: By "the elements in odd positions are already sorted," do you mean they're already in their final positions, or just that they're in-order with respect to each other?

Comment: they are in-order with respect to each other